# How to get values of query parameters

Tags: meteor

I have an url `www.xyz.com/?R1=xxx&R2=yyy&R3=zzz`

How can i get value of query parameters `R1`, `R2` and `R3`?

I am beginner in Meteor.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Meteor-specific and depends on your router. Here are some links to the section about query parameters for each of the most common routers used in Meteor:

- [Iron Router](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-parameters)
- [Flow Router](https://guide.meteor.com/routing.html#url-pattern-matching)
- [React Router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/06-params)